# C++ error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am getting this error for every int in this section of code;

```
if(choice==2) {
    inssort(int *a, int numLines);
}
if(choice==3) {
    bubblesort(int *a, int numLines);
}
if(choice==4) {
    mergesort(int *a, int numLines);
}
if(choice==5) {
    radixsort(int *a, int numLines);
}
if(choice==6) {
    return 0;
}
```

Thats where I call the functions in main.  If you are wondering I am writing a small program that gives the user a choice when sorting a list between 4 different types of sorting algorithms.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use the declaration types when you're ***calling*** the functions. Only when you ***declare*** them are they needed:

```
if(choice==2)
{
    inssort(a, numLines);
}
if(choice==3)
{
    bubblesort(a, numLines);
}
if(choice==4) 
{
    mergesort(a, numLines);
}
if(choice==5) 
{
    radixsort(a, numLines);
}
if(choice==6) 
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, it's not a matter of not _needing_ them so much as it's _illegal_ to put them there. But, other than my semantic nit-picking, you're right, so +1.

Answer (score 1):

You're using function *declaration* syntax to make function *calls*.  That's not necessary, and (as you have discovered) doesn't even work.  You can just write

```
if (choice == 2)
    inssort(a, numLines);
// etc
```

By the way, a `switch` would be more idiomatic here.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(choice==2)
{
 inssort(int *a, int numLines);
}
```

your code turn to this

```
if(choice==2)
{
 inssort(&a, numLines);
}
```